# Getting the values in a dropdownbox from javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Does anyone know how to get the values from an asp dropdownbox (not just the selected one) using javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean a `<select>` element - just loop over its `options` property.

```
var options = refToMyForm.elements.mySelect.options;
for (var i = 0, j = options.length; i < j; i++) {
    var option = option[i];
    var value = option.value;
}
```

Comment: actually, an <asp:DropDownList/>, but they're effectively the same thing, so thanks =]

Comment: I'm assuming you are asking about client-side JavaScript, which only cares about the document that the browser sees. It has no idea about the ASP ... and since I'm not as ASP programmer, I can only guess :) It does help to reduce examples as much as possible.

Comment: sorry, I always forget that asp controls are generally just html controls with server side methods, I normally only do ASP programming!